# Pass memory address to multiprocessing.Process outside of its memory context

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing

I'd like to achieve something that is most possibly not possible, potentially dangerous of very certainly despicable:

I have a global complex data object. I'd like to pass its memory address, which is of course outside of the spawned process's memory so it can alter the same data that is on global scope.

By now, you got that I want to escape python's limitation to only share primitive data objects between processes.

On what level does my evil plan fail?

Here's some pseudo-phython-code just in case:

```
class ComplexClass:
    def __init__(self, complex_data):
        self.complex_data = complex_data

    def change_data(self):
        self.complex_data = changes


complex_class_object = ComplexClass(...)
        
        
def data_operation(memory_address_of_complex_data):
    _complex_class_object = retrieve_data(memory_address_of_complex_data)
    _complex_class_object.change_data()


memory_address_of_complex_data = memory_address_of(complex_class_object)

process = multiprocessing.Process(
    target=data_operation, 
    args=(memory_address_of_complex_data, *args), 
    kwargs=kwargs)
    
process.start()
process.join()
```

Comment: "Hey, there's a really funny scene on page 163 of this book that I'm reading!  You should turn to page 163 of whatever book you have handy, so that you can read it too!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the address that you see is the **virtual address** of the data in the process's virtual address space, it's **not the physical address** on the memory chip, so if two processes try to access the same virtual address, they are accessing two different locations on your RAM chip

the operating system is mostly responsible for the mapping between the virtual and the physical addresses. (usually through hardware support)

---

there are utilities for allowing one process to access another process's memory and manipulate it, such as [shared memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) blocks, or forcefully (through admin privilege) using something like [WriteProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory)

the main limitation of shared memory is that you need to know the size in advance, so it's not suitable for storing python objects, instead it can store buffers for raw binary data like numpy arrays. ( you can have a numpy array shared between processes)

if you must work with python objects you can store the object in another process entirely, and manipulate it with proxies through IPC using a [multiprocessing.Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Manager).